# js open txt file read line by line and turn it to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, fetch

The problem is that I want to use the array elsewhere in my code. But I do not know how to access it?
Is there any other way to read the file and turn it into an array that I can use?

```
var dir = 'file.txt';

function file() {
const fileUrl = dir;

fetch(fileUrl)
    .then( response => response.text() )
    .then( text => readFile(text) )
}

function readFile(text) {
var lines = text.split('\n');
var array = [];
var str;

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var str = lines[i];
    tmp = str.split(",");
    array[i] = tmp;
}

}
```

file.txt

W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W
B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B
C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C
D,D,D,D,D,D,D,D,D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

To use that you would need to return the array from the function so you will need to do something like this.

```
var dir = 'file.txt';
var result; // Just to store the output

function file() {
    const fileUrl = dir;

    fetch(fileUrl)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            result = readFile(text)
        })
}

function readFile(text) {
    var lines = text.split('\n');
    var array = [];
    var str;

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var str = lines[i];
        tmp = str.split(",");
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
     

    return array;
}
```

Notice the variable result on the second line.

Comment: I have tried this before I posted the question. And same as the last time I get "Undefined" back when I try to run it in the console.